# I disable a module while install, how to enable again? - Magento2

Tags: magento2, module

While I install Magento2, I choose disable Mage_notification module

how can I re enable this module again after complete install?

All the module I disable during install are not showing Config - Advanced - Advanced

Comment: modules folder... look for the name and then add false > true

Comment: If this answer helped you than please mark it as correct. Thank you.

Comment: app/etc/config.php open and write that module set to 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Using Magento2 Backend:**

Stores > Configuration > Advanced (dropdown) > Advanced.

Find the module, Use the dropdown to enable it. See: https://yadi.sk/i/Aq0VAR_Ls5xgd

**Using CLI:**

To find out which modules are enabled/disabled.

From your Magento installation root, run:

```
php bin/magento module:status
```

Once you know which Module you want enabled, run:

```
php bin/magento module:enable Magento_ModuleName
```

In case you need to disable a module, run:

```
php bin/magento module:disable Magento_ModuleName
```

Answer (score -1):

app/etc/modules

Find your module name and enable it...

```
<active>false</active>
```

to

```
<active>true</active>
```

Comment: The op is asking about Magento 2 not Magento 1

Comment: ahh... I wasn't aware of a difference. Thank you for clearing that up.